# I have string with number, how to get number out of this string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have string something like `ACGI SHIPPING (3471)` and I need to get 3471 number out of it.

If there is no number just print 0, in SQL Server

Comment: Is that the only pattern?

Comment: yes only this pattern

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = 'ACGI SHIPPING (3471)'
SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @s) > 0 
            THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @s), LEN(@s)), ')', '') 
            ELSE 0 END
```

You are searching for first digit and take substring from that position to end. And then replace `')'` with blank.